# validation in mobile application

Tags: javascript, html, devextreme

I am facing some problem while implementing validation in a view.

I am trying to follow one of the  Devextreme example in the site.
http://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/#demo/editors-validation-overview

Error what I am getting Is "**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'validate' of undefined**". while clicking the finish button.

This is the code what I am using:`
    
        
            User Name:
            
        
        
            Password:
            
        
        
            Re-enter Password:

```
PaMobile01.popup = function (params, viewInfo) {
"use strict";

var openTabsAsRoot = viewInfo.layoutController.name === "split",
    isReady = $.Deferred();



function handleViewShown() {
    loadopetions();
}


function validateAndSubmit(params) {
    var result = params.validationGroup.validate();
    if (result.isValid) {
        DevExpress.ui.notify({
            message: "You have submitted the form",
            position: {
                my: "center top",
                at: "center top"
            }
        }, "success", 3000);
    }
}

function loadopetions() {
    $("#tbx_userneme").dxTextBox({
        placeholder: 'Required',
    }).dxValidator({
        validationRules: [{
            type: "required",
            message: "City is required"
        }, {
            type: "pattern",
            pattern: "^[a-zA-Z]+$",
            message: "Do not use digits in the City name."
        }, {
            type: "pattern",
            pattern: "^.{2,}$",
            message: "City must have at least 2 symbols"
        }]
    });

    $("#tbx_password").dxTextBox({
        placeholder: 'Required',
    }).dxValidator({
        validationRules: [{
            type: "required",
            message: "City is required"
        }, {
            type: "pattern",
            pattern: "^[a-zA-Z]+$",
            message: "Do not use digits in the City name."
        }, {
            type: "pattern",
            pattern: "^.{2,}$",
            message: "City must have at least 2 symbols"
        }]
    });

    $("#tbx_repassword").dxTextBox({
        placeholder: 'Required',
    }).dxValidator({
        validationRules: [{
            type: "required",
            message: "City is required"
        }, {
            type: "pattern",
            pattern: "^[a-zA-Z]+$",
            message: "Do not use digits in the City name."
        }, {
            type: "pattern",
            pattern: "^.{2,}$",
            message: "City must have at least 2 symbols"
        }]
    });

}

function handlefinish() {
    validateAndSubmit(params);
}
return {
    isReady: isReady.promise(),
    viewShown: handleViewShown,
    openTabsAsRoot: openTabsAsRoot,
    handlefinish: handlefinish
}
```

};

Answer (score 0):

The function that invokes validation must receive params argument. Look how it's done in the tutorial:

```
$("#button").dxButton({
    text: "Submit",
    type: "success", 
    onClick: validateAndSubmit
});
```

The library is handling this params object. Now in your code you hide that function that the library expects behind `handlefinish` which has no arguments.
You can either add `params` as a parameter to the function definition:

```
function handlefinish(params) {
    validateAndSubmit(params);
}
```

Or return that function itself:

```
return {
    isReady: isReady.promise(),
    viewShown: handleViewShown,
    openTabsAsRoot: openTabsAsRoot,
    validateAndSubmit: validateAndSubmit
}
```

Also look how you manage that module `PaMobile01.popup` function, try to follow the tutorial.

UPDATE:

Look at documentation for re-enter password validation: [comparerule](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxValidator/Validation_Rules/CompareRule/?version=15_2)

According to the docs, you need to add a validation rule to the validator of `#tbx_repassword`:
`[{ type: 'compare', comparisonTarget: getPassword }]`

where getPassword is a function like:

```
function getPassword(){
  return document.getElementById('tbx_password').value;
}
```

Comment: Hi I tried that too but it is also throwing error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'validate' of undefined"  in validateAndSubmit function

Comment: Hi I am able to solve it now thanx a lot for your help.

Comment: Currently I am facing some other issue with comparison of two dxtextbox value.
Like password and reenterpassword in the same above code.
can you please help me with this.

Comment: Hello @Orif I tried the same but still I am not getting even after giving the same values to both the textbox its showing validation message that the values are not same